# How to use multiple lines to instead of linear list in TSConfig addToList?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tsconfig

In TSConfig I sometimes have long lists of items when using `addToList` / `removeFromList`

This makes it hard to read/edit. Is there a way to format it as a multiline list?

Eg. What I have:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems := addToList(item1,item2,item3)
```

What I want:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems := addToList(
    item1
    item2
    item3
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType { 
  removeItems := addToList(item1)
  removeItems := addToList(item2)
  removeItems := addToList(item3)
}
```

Is the best typoscript can do